# Button stop functioning after turning on and off once

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

App has an imagebutton which turn screen brightness on and off, but after turning clicking it on and off one time, the button is not working anymore. Does anyone have idea, what is wrong with the code?

```
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class ScreenFlashlight extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String tag;
    private static final String TAG = tag ;
    private boolean brightnessOnOff;
    private ImageButton screenFlashOnOffButton;

    public ScreenFlashlight() throws Settings.SettingNotFoundException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_flashlight);
        screenFlashOnOffButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashOnOffButton);
        brightnessOnOff = false;


    }
    public void screenFlashButtonClicked(View view) {

            try {
                if (brightnessOnOff) {

                    turnBrightnessOff();
                    Log.d(TAG, "screenFlashButtonClicked: ");
                } else {
                    brightnessOnOff = true;
                    turnBrightnessOn();
                    Log.d(TAG, "screenFlashButtonClicked: ");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }



    private void turnBrightnessOn() {
        try {
            screenFlashOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.screenonbutton);
            int currentBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            //Screen refresh to add brightness

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = currentBrightness/ 100.0f;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void turnBrightnessOff() {
        try {
            screenFlashOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.screenoffbutton);
            int currentBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            //Refresh screen

            WindowManager.LayoutParams lpp = getWindow().getAttributes();
            lpp.screenBrightness = currentBrightness;
            getWindow().setAttributes(lpp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set `brightnessOnOff` to false when the brightness is turned off, so it will have value `true` after you press the button the first time. So your code will enter the `if` block everytime. What you need to do is set `brightnessOnOff` to false when you turn off the brightness, and set it to true when you turn the brightness on again. Basically, you need to alternate `brightnessOnOff` between `true` and `false` for it to work correctly